# ASP.NET Performance Counter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the asp.net web api 2.0 and Elastic/Logstash/Kibana stack.
Now i want to measue how long my methods need to finish. Things i tried:

- Action Filter Attribute / AOP
  I put an instance of Stopwatch into request.properties and measured it this way. It's positive that I can connect the method name and value and it's easy to get the results into logstash. But if it's possible I'm looking for a way that is more generic and maybe already implementet in asp.net.
- ASP.NET Performance Counter
  I found the Request Execution Time metrics and can check the value on perfmon. I can't connect the values to the requests, because i only get the value that belongs to the last requests, not the current (of cause, the request is still in progess).
  I also checked libs like Metrics.NET which also uses those counters and Logary. With Metrics.NET I was able to send my data to logstash, but I wasn't able to filter them so it was a mass of data. With logary I configured the logstash endpoint but data didn't reach logstash.

Has anyone more experience with those and can tell me which one you prefere or fits best for my needs?

Comment: did you tried using `PerformanceCounter class` for any ***ASP.NET Performance Counter*** ? any sample about it in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend against using anything in code as this may add overhead to your performance.

.NET performance counter logs is a better solution but I'm not sure if LogStash can easily ingest these.

I know a lot of people prefer to aggregate the raw IIS log files into LogStash. There's some guides available here:

- http://jacob.ludriks.com/2014/07/10/IIS-logging-to-the-ELK-stack/
- http://improveandrepeat.com/2014/11/using-logstash-to-analyse-iis-log-files-with-kibana/
- https://adammills.wordpress.com/2014/02/21/logstash-and-iis/

Comment: Use  `PerformanceCounter class` for any ***ASP.NET Performance Counter*** is add _overhead_ to performance ? Which more value information: ***ASP.NET Performance Counter***  or ***IIS log*** ? Anyways, ***ASP.NET Performance Counter***  not easy use with **LogStash and Kibana**, maybe.